# TYPO3 & tt_news - internal Link without language parameters

Tags: typo3, multilingual, tt-news

i have a Problem regarding TYPO3 and the extension tt_news. 
I have a multilingual Site with 2 Languages, english and german. The news on the site are generatet by the extension tt_news - everything is working fine except one thing:

When i put an internal direct link in the news body, the language parameter is lost. So when the user klicks on the Link, it always comes back to the default language. How can i make TYPO3 generate the links with the selected language parameter, or how can i add them?

Comment: How do you add the link? Is it a complete url? Or do you use the link picker?

Comment: Are you directly Paste Link on RTE ? or You can use Insert Link Option ?